# how to load forms automatically

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I wan't to load my form automatically with the data out of the database.

my code for the inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="form[settings_maintenance_text]" placeholder="Die Website befindet sich aus XYZ Gründen im Wartungsmodus" class="form-control">
```

in my database looks like this:

id_option | option_value | option_key

0 | test | settings_maintenance_text

and I try to load the "test" in form[settings_maintenance_text] but it doesn't work with

```
$_REQUEST["form[settings_maintenance_text]"] = $settings->readSettings("settings_maintenance_text"); // returns test
```

the input has no value. How I can solve my problem?
sorry for my very bad english

Comment: What does the database connecting and querying take place?

Comment: You're overriding the data that was sent from the browser with this code. Is that the behavior you wanted?

Comment: the class "settings" extends my mysql class where the connection & quering things are done

Comment: @crush what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this

```
<?php
$maintenanceText = $settings->readSettings("settings_maintenance_text");
?>

<input type="text" value="<?php echo $maintenanceText; ?>" name="form[settings_maintenance_text]" placeholder="Die Website befindet sich aus XYZ Gründen im Wartungsmodus" class="form-control">
```

Comment: I work with the template engine smarty and it looks that i must assign an array with all the data :( maybe i should make it so: `{$settings.option_key}`